# Is there a URL parameter in Grafana to View graphs where alerts are firing only?

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I've made dashboards with a number of concerns/graphs.  Generally not for one specific area, but as an overview of the system where I'm gathering metrics.  When I have an alert firing for one of them the little 'Heart' above the graph lights up red and I'd like to maybe go straight to a view of that graph.

Admittedly, there could be more than one graph that is alerting.  But rather than search the page for the red heart it would be cool to generate a new view from just the ones alerting or open the first in view mode.

Perhaps this already exists?  Via a URL parameter perhaps?

Comment: The alert list panel provides something similar to what you asked. You can't see the actually graphs that are firing the alerts but you have an overview of all the alerts. https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/panels/alertlist/

Comment: I miss the old Grafana. All my alerts take me directly to the panel that is alerting. Now it takes me to the Alert rules page.

Answer (score 0):

Within your Grafana config you have to change the domain and root_url under the [server] settings. This will then redirect you to the graph that fired the alert.

```
[server]
domain = {your_domain}
root_url = https://%(domain)s
```